# Generate answers object with the answers filled in this case in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I generate objects in `answers` like this :

```
<el-input :id="'question_' + question.id" v-model="answers[question.id]"></el-input>
```

Which gives, when I fill in inputs:

```
Answers: object
{
 "19":"Hello",
 "20":"Test",
 "22":"04718810200",
 "26":"Belgium"
 }
```

I save this data in my database. Now, I would like to display the server's collected data in "answers" so that users can edit their data.

Only, `answers` is empty when creating the page and is generated according to the fields that the user has filled (as seen above).

This is what one of my data collected from the server looks like :

```
questions:Object
  created_at:"2019-08-13 12:33:48"
  deleted_at:null
  id:8
  lang:"fr"
  part:"bilan-first"
  profile_id:1
   questions:Array[66]
     0:Object
       answer:Object
         answer:"Jimmy"
         created_at:"2019-08-18 13:37:20"
         deleted_at:null
         id:4
         question_id:19
         updated_at:"2019-08-18 14:35:33"
         user_id:10
       answered:true
       category_id:8
       created_at:"2019-08-14 13:36:52"
       deleted_at:null
       id:19
       position:0
       question:"<p>Prénom</p>"
       type:"label-input"
    1:Object
    …
```

How to generate `answers{}` with the answers filled in this case? I must have as key the `id` of `answer` and as value `answers`.

I tried that, but it didn't work :

```js
axios.get('/bilan/' + this.$route.params.id).then(response => {
  this.questions = response.data.data
  response.data.data.questions.forEach(function(answer) {
    if (answer.answer) {
      this.answers[answer.answer.id] = answer.answer.answer
    }
  })
})
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a `v-for` loop rendering this part? `<el-input :id="'question_' + question.id" v-model="answers[question.id]"></el-input>`

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57546302/impossible-to-update-v-model-with-inputs