# Impossible to update v-model with inputs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I generate objects in answers like this:

```html
<el-input :id="'question_' + question.id" v-model="answers[question.id]"></el-input>
```

...which gives the following output when I fill in inputs:

```
Answers: object
{
 "19":"Hello",
 "20":"Test",
 "22":"04718810200",
 "26":"Belgium"
}
```

When users come back to the page, I want them to see their answers. I collect them like this in my `axios` call:

```js
axios.get('/bilan/' + this.$route.params.id).then(response => {
  this.questions = response.data.data

  this.questions.questions.forEach(question => {
    if (question.answer) {
      this.answers[question.id] = question.answer.answer
    }
  })
})
```

It fulfills my object answers, and my inputs are correctly filled with the answers saved, but unfortunately, it does not have the expected behavior. When I want to modify an input, it does not work. Nothing fills up.

Why?

Comment: Where is question defined in your code and what defines it? Can you show some more code and also what is fetched from the server exactly

Comment: Don't entirely follow but `this.answers[question.id] = ...` makes me think of the property addition caveat for reactivity: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @skirlte stated, there are [change detection caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats).

> Due to limitations in JavaScript, Vue cannot detect the following
> changes to an array:
>
> When you directly set an item with the index, e.g.
> `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue`. When you modify the length of the
> array, e.g. `vm.items.length = newLength`.
> So change this lined of code:

```js
this.answers[question.id] = question.answer.answer
```

to

```js
this.$set(this.answers, question.id, question.answer.answer)
```